# Delete entity with self-referencing foreign key using recursive function in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project using Entity Framework I am using code first approach. I am having a problem with deleting an entity with a self-referencing foreign key and it's related entities using a recursive function.

I am deleting using recursive function because it is not possible to set delete cascade for self-referencing foreign key in SQL Server. When I delete, it throws a stack overflow exception if entity has related entities to be deleted. Because recursive function never stop calling. It become infinite.

This is my entity class with self-referencing FK

```
public class Category
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(55)]
        public string MmName { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I am deleting in model using recursive function:

```
public List<int> deletedIds = new List<int>();

        public Category Delete(Category category)
        {
            if(category!=null)
            {
                int intentionId = category.Id;
                if(category.Categories!=null && category.Categories.Count>0)
                {
                    RelatedCategories(category.Categories);
                }
                deletedIds.Add(intentionId);
                if(deletedIds.Count>0)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Category> categories = context.Categories.Where(x => deletedIds.Contains(x.Id));
                    if(categories!=null && categories.Count()>0)
                    {
                        context.Categories.RemoveRange(categories);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            return category;
        }

        private void RelatedCategories(IEnumerable<Category> categories)
        {
            foreach(var c in categories)
            {
                deletedIds.Add(c.Id);
                while (c.Categories!=null && c.Categories.Count > 0)
                {
                    RelatedCategories(c.Categories);
                }
            }        
        }
```

I am deleting data in this structure

[image]

I am deleting test1. But when recursive function get called in itself, it is just keep passing List with test2 all the time. How can I fix my code? How can I delete category and its related categories using recursive function?

I tried this to stop recursion. It just cannot stop and just the same.

```
private void RelatedCategories(IEnumerable<Category> categories)
        {
            Category repeatedCategory = null;
            if(categories!=null && categories.Count()>0 && deletedIds.Count>0)
            {
                repeatedCategory = categories.FirstOrDefault(x => deletedIds.Contains(categories.Select(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault()));
            }
            if(repeatedCategory!=null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach(var c in categories)
            {
                deletedIds.Add(c.Id);
                while (c.Categories!=null && c.Categories.Count > 0)
                {
                    RelatedCategories(c.Categories);
                }
            }        
        }
```

Comment: I found error and I will post answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error. It was my fault with recursive. I used while loop in the recursive function. So it become infinite loop. Actualy I needed to use if statement instead. I just replaced with this function. It worked fine.

```
private void RelatedCategories(IEnumerable<Category> categories)
        {
            foreach (var c in categories)
            {
                deletedIds.Add(c.Id);
                if(c.Categories!=null && c.Categories.Any())
                {
                    SetRelatedCategories(c.Categories);
                }
            }
        }
```